# container view constraint issues programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, constraints

I am trying to include a container UIView right above my tabBar however it doesnt seem to be displayed on my view because what i believe to be constraint issues. I would like my container view to look so in the view. [image]

However my container is not showing in the view at all.
Here is my code:

```
self.mapContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.mapContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    self.mapContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.mapContainer.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(self.mapContainer)

    //constraints of the map view
        let heightTabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
        self.mapContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant : (heightTabBar)! + 220).isActive = true
        self.mapContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        //self.topContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.mapContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
        //self.mapContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive =  true
        self.mapContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.mapContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

where am I going wrong here to where my container is not displaying
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You push your view with a positive value at your bottom anchor outside of the view. That's the reason why you don't see it.

**Solution:**

Instead of adding with `(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant : (heightTabBar)! + 220)` you should subtract with `self.mapContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant : -(heightTabBar! + 220)).isActive = true` at your bottomAnchor. You should also make your leading anchor of the container depend on the leading anchor of the view, the same for the trailing anchor. Also you need to set a negative value for your constant to your trailing anchor to add padding on the right side. **Keep in mind:** If you want to push from top and left then **add** and if you want to push from right and bottom then **subtract**

This should help you (Hints are in the code comments):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var mapContainer:UIView!

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    self.mapContainer = UIView()
    self.mapContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.mapContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    self.mapContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.mapContainer.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(self.mapContainer)


    //constraints of the map view
    let heightTabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
    // You need to subtract to push from the bottom of the view
    self.mapContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant : -(heightTabBar! + 220)).isActive = true
    self.mapContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.mapContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

    // Your leading anchor of map container should depend on the leading anchor of the view
    self.mapContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    // Your trailingAnchor anchor of map container should depend on the trailingAnchor anchor of the view
    // Here you need to subtract to push from the right
    self.mapContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Result should look similar to this:

[image]

Result on iPhone5S simulator:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to make this work how i wanted based your solution for the iphone 6s however it doesnt seem to work on the iphone 5S. would you happen to know any reason why ?

Comment: Yeah, glad that I could help you! I think I will have look later what the reason might be, but if this answer solves this question, you should maybe create a new question with your current code and explain your new problem and you can link it here in the comment

Comment: Tested in the simulator with iPhone5s and it looks good to me. Maybe you can describe in a new question what you expect and what doesn't work for you on iPhone5S compared to iPhone6 @Aboogie